# Notepad++ Fail at syntax lighter

Tags: syntax, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

Notepad++ failed to light my code as an Assembly one. It Wrotte it as standard notepad text :(
How can I get it working again??
It worked fine yesterday

Comment: In the navbar, go to Language->A->Assembly.

Comment: Tryed but without succes!

Comment: Reinstall :) I gave you the link :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels like you deleted some syntax engines from your Notepad++ folder! 
Reinstaling app may fix the problem :)

Get it here: http://download.tuxfamily.org/notepadplus/6.5.2/npp.6.5.2.Installer.exe